# Generate random float number in column as element

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any way I can generate random float array as element in 'Price' column?

```
import pandas as pd 
data = pd.read_csv("C:\\users\\Hp\\Downloads\\Stock.csv")
data = data.rename(columns={'Date': 'Exportation Date'})
data['Exportation Month'] = data['Exportation Date'].str[6:7] 

data['Price'] = 1.2

data.head()
```

Output (I deleted some columns due to large size that couldn't fit the question section):

```
Exportation Month   Price
0   2               1.2
1   6               1.2
2   1               1.2
3   8               1.2
4   8               1.2
```

Output I wanted (Assume those numbers in 'Price' are randomly generated):

```
Exportation Month   Price
0   2               5.4
1   6               2.5
2   1               4.4
3   8               17.1
4   8               2.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want a price between 0 and 100 with 1 decimal, you can do it that way:

```
from random import uniform

data['Price'] = [round(uniform(0, 100), 1) for i in range(len(data))]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
from random import randrange

randObj = f'{randrange(99)}.{randrange(99)}'
data['Price'] = float(randObj)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `numpy.random`

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Fake Data
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2],
                   "b": [3, 4]})
# Add Price
df["Price"] = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=10, size=len(df))

# Eventually use 2 decimal places only.
df["Price"] = df["Price"].round(2)
```